# Using Java collections during parsing log files

Tags: java, parsing, collections

1. After reading a log file I want to give the raw log (a String) to another component which only parse the log.
2. Each log entry should be parsed.
3. Each parsed data should be assigned to a particular `LogEntry` object.
4. All `LogEntry` objects should be given to passed to another component stores them in a database.
   Now the question is: Is it a good idea to keep the parsed `LogEntry` objects in a Java Collection (such an `ArrayList`) until the raw log is completely parsed, then pass this collection to the storing component?

Note that I want to keep the single responsibility principle, so i don't want to parse the log entries and store them in the same time.
If you have any other suggestions let me know please.

Comment: It's a design decision. Single responsibility is good to have. Now logs are typically long files. So if you have the RAM to have all objects in the collection and then save - then go ahead. Since I don't typically have such huge RAM space, I would look for buffer storage and DB insert as soon as I reach 70% buffer. Now if DB is NOSQL, I would wait till 90% else won't take the chance.

Comment: Assuming your other component is java too. Why aren't you just passing the (serialized) `LogEntry`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to use a ArrayList because the "enlarge"-process is verry expensiv. I'd **use LinkedList** instead. You only need to add and remove the logs.

The next point is about memory utilisation, if you have enough memory why not.

Comment: Is there another way to keep the log entries and pass them to the datastore component?

Comment: Of course, its only one way. You could use a concurrent linked list and work with a producer consumer pattern.As example: http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why it wouldn't be unless there was some use case benefit to creating a larger LogEntryList type of class. I would avoid arrayList though in favor of linkedList. ArrayList is not always the fastest to add things to. Look at something like this: http://bigocheatsheet.com/ to see what structure best fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is right to save data to collection. but you should use hash set i think data would be in large amount. it will provide fast access even with bulky data.